# Copy a single file to multiple directories in Ant

Tags: file, ant

I would like to copy one file to multiple directories during a build process.

The value in `${prop.fmt}` has two directories, I just want to copy a single WAR file to those two directories:

```
/apps/phxadmin-dev/devd/ui_tomcats/tomcat_c345tczuwdvd2/webapps
/apps/phxadmin-dev/devd/ui_tomcats/tomcat_c404gxduwdvd1/webapps
```

My Ant script:

```
<target name="test" >
    <dirset id="dir.name" dir="${phx.tomcat.dir}" includes="*/webapps"/>
    <property name="prop.dist.contents" refid="dir.name"/>      
    <loadresource property="prop.fmt">
        <string value="${prop.dist.contents}"/>
        <filterchain>
            <tokenfilter>
                <replaceregex pattern=";" replace="${line.separator}" flags="g"/>
            </tokenfilter>
            <prefixlines prefix="${phx.tomcat.dir}/" />
        </filterchain>
    </loadresource>
    <echo message="${prop.fmt}"/>
    <copy file="${phx.deploy.dir}/${war.file.name}" todir="${prop.fmt}"/>
</target>
```

Please can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<copy>` task can copy to multiple destinations by:

- setting the `enableMultipleMappings` attribute to `true`
- and using a `<scriptmapper>`

In your example, the entire `<target name="test">` block can be replaced with...

```
<target name="test">
    <dirset id="dir.name" dir="${phx.tomcat.dir}" includes="*/webapps"/>
    <copy todir="${phx.tomcat.dir}" enableMultipleMappings="true" verbose="true">
        <fileset file="${phx.deploy.dir}/${war.file.name}"/>
        <scriptmapper language="javascript">
        <![CDATA[
            var dirSet = project.getReference( "dir.name" );
            var ds = dirSet.getDirectoryScanner( project );
            var includes = ds.getIncludedDirectories( );
            for ( var i = 0; i < includes.length; i++ )
            {
                self.addMappedName( includes[i] + "/" + source );
            }
        ]]>
        </scriptmapper>
    </copy>
</target>
```

Running the above script results in output that looks somewhat like the following:

```
test:
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /apps/phxadmin-dev/devd/ui_tomcats
     [copy] Copying my.war to /apps/phxadmin-dev/devd/ui_tomcats/tomcat_c345tczuwdvd2/webapps/my.war
     [copy] Copying my.war to /apps/phxadmin-dev/devd/ui_tomcats/tomcat_c404gxduwdvd1/webapps/my.war
```